# How to create & use Shared Library in C++

Tags: c++

How do i access the following function using external dynamically linked library?

```
double sum(double a, double b)
{
     return (a+b);
}
```

**P.S> I don't 've any idea about these stuffs. Just wanna know how things work!

Operating System: Windows(preferable) & Linux

Answer (score 0):

Link against the library and declare the prototype (usually done by including the header where the function is declared).

Under Windows, you have to explicitly mark the function as import/export (google for `declspec(dllimport)` and `declspec(dllexport`).

Comment: what are declspec() dllimport & dllexport ?
Pls brief me about all these.

Comment: Searched google. Is that declspec() microsoft specific (i.e. VC++ specific) ?

Actually, Just need a generic one.
I use Code::Blocks with "MingW64" compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It very much depends on the compiler. On some systems (Windows), for example, you have to add some things in front - __declspec(dllexport) / __declspec(dllimport). On others (Linux), this is not needed.

[Here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) is a nice tutorial on how to do it with gcc in Linux.

Comment: Pls also specify tutorial for "Windows".
Many tuts available for Linux. Cudn't find any for Win

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx